# Looking for a proper solution for a case which requires: Service, Timer, GPS, Notification, Activity

Tags: java, android, gps, android-notifications

In my Android application I have this scenario:
An activity starts a service.
The service needs to run in foreground.
That's why I've created a notification.
When the service starts, will start a GPS class.
At each second, the service will retrieve data from the GPS class and update the notification text. And also broadcast to the activity that data.
To check at every second, I need a task repeater.

The current code fails probably because of the performance.
The last message I got was !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!

This service can work up to 5-8 hours.
Most of the time the app fails after 15-40 minutes, so is quite slow to debug it.

Is there any proper solution for this case?

Comment: Are you using scheduling services?

Comment: I use TimerTask, but no AlarmManager or so

Comment: Timer Task with simple services. right?

Comment: Yes, and a Handler - if it worth to know

Comment: Ok that's fine.....so what;s your problem???

Comment: The service stops from functioning after 15-40 minutes and I get the message !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72572/discussion-between-m-d-and-george-i).

Answer (score 0):

The story is long, but I'll try to simplify the answer.
Just for future reading.

I solved the problem.
I've used a simple Service, a foreground sticky Notification, a Handler, a BroadcastReceiver, a TimerTask, and of course a GPS class.

The issue I had was caused by the fact that the service was updating the notification every second and the app was using too many resources for that.